# Loop to scrape multiple web pages not looping

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape the top 500 restaurants in Singapore on TripAdvisor; however, my current code only pulls the first 30 and keeps looping until it prints the first 30 until it hits 500 records. I want it to print the first 30, then the next 30 on the next page and so on. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code to see why it's doing this.

```
#loop to move into the next pages. entries are in increments of 30 per page
for i in range(0, 500, 30):
    #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa
    #change key and geography here
    url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294265-oa' + str(i) + 'Singapore.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = r1.text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
    for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
        #change key here
        restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294265-' + link.get('href')
        print restaurant_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making incorrect URLs here:

```
url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294265-oa' + str(i) + 'Singapore.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
```

The correct URL format should be:

```
url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294265-oa{0}-Singapore.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'.format(i)
```

Note the dash after the "page offset".

---

I would also maintain a web-scraping session and improve the variable naming:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    for offset in range(0, 500, 30):
        url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294265-oa{0}-Singapore.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'.format(offset)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.select('a.property_title'):
            restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294265-' + link.get('href')
            print(restaurant_url)
```

Also, think about *adding delays* between subsequent requests to be a better [web-scraping citizen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette).

Comment: Worked like a charm. And thank you for linking that session post. I am new to this community so anything is helpful!